# JavaScript not working the first time but works after refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, colors

I want the links to change to a random color every time I hover on them. It only works after I refreshed the page. Does anyone know why this happened? I don't have a lot of experience with JavaScript.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $( "a" ).hover(function() {
    $ (this).css("color",getRandomColor());
    }, function() {
      $(this).css("color","");
    }
  );

  function getRandomColor () {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
  }
})
```

```css
a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2><a href="https://www.google.com/">TEST</a></h2>
```

I tried to modify the script but failed to make it work.

Comment: That code seems to work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you dynamically loading `<a>` after the page loads? The code you are using will only bind to the `<a>` on the page when it runs, which could result in an asynchronous timing issue.

Also, from the [hover docs](https://api.jquery.com/hover/):

> This API is deprecated. Use .on( "[mouseenter](https://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/)", handlerIn ).on(
> "[mouseleave](https://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/)", handlerOut ) instead.

Using the [.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/) method allows you to provide a selector for the second argument, which works great for dynamically added content, because you put the handler on the static parent element, rather than each dynamically added element:

```
$('body')
  .on('mouseenter', 'a', handlerIn )
  .on('mouseleave', 'a', handlerOut );
```

Here is an example of randomly added anchors that randomly change color on hover:

```js
$('body')
  .on('mouseenter', 'a', function() {
    this.style.color = RndHexClr();
  })
  .on('mouseleave', 'a', function() {
    this.style.color = '';
  });
  
  
  
function RndHexClr () {
  return '#' + '123456'.split('').map(() =>
    '23456789ABCDEF'.split('')[Math.floor(Math.random() * 14)]).join('');
}
 
 $('body').append('0123456789'.split('').map(() => `<a>${RndHexClr()}</a>`));
```

```css
a { display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```